# How to create a lookup in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, menu, cakephp-3.0, lookup, dropdown

I'm in the process of converting a 10 year old PHP application. After my boss hired a php consultant, he has set up a CakePHP application environment and we are learning as we go. (fun, I know). Also, I come from a javascript/sharepoint background and have not had a lot of php experience.

As a test, I created a basic address table with these fields: firstname, lastname, state, phonenumber. I've been using justice league members as names and other test data to populate my table. Baked it just fine, default bootstrap pages are working.

I decided I wanted to add a dropdown field called current status, and for now just to keep it simple I wanted the choices: alive, dead.I created the column in my address table.

I created a second table called statuses and pointed the status column in my first table to the status table, using the status id as the foriegn key.

Baked my new table and rebaked my old one.

The status drop down does not give my choices of dead or alive, If I click in the field I get an up or down arrow, and based on which one you click, it either increments or decrements by 1. So the first time I click it inserts a 0. If I go up or down, it adds or takes away one.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I'm guessing there is some additional code I need to add to the MVC?

Comment: You say you re-baked your old table. Does that include the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, if this works, then a lot is working :-). Now to the following: set in the **Status Model** a query like this:

```
public function getStatus()
{
    $opt = $this->Status->find('list', array(...));
    return $opt;
}
```

Then get the list over to the **Adress Controller** like this:

```
$this->loadModel('Status');
$opt => $this->Status->getStatus();
$this->set('opt', $opt);
```

Now you are able to access the $opt in the view file.
Just delete this line in the view:

```
$opts = array('0' => __('dead'), '1' => __('alive'));
```

And it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple. Ad to your table this row (only to understand how it works): 'status' as typ "tinyint(1)". Then set this in your view file:

```
$opts = array('0' => __('dead'), '1' => __('alive'));
```

When you create the inputfield, do it like that:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Address.status', array('options' => $opts, 'label'
=> __('Status')));
```

This should work.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I have built an example like yours that works. My issue is, for a lot of the application that I am porting over, select/dropdown content is going to be based off other tables as the user moves through the application adding government contract data. The thing is, I've had it working befire, but it was only showing the id of the four items in the table instead of the name.